# SQL query for count all(unknown, known), unknown, known customer, identify uniquely by Phone Mac address

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table 1(Customer Table)

Id, CustomerId, IsKnownCustomer,phonemacaddress

1,  NULL         0              00:9a:34:cf:a4

2,  004024       1              00:6f:64:cf:a0:93

3,  004024       1              00:6f:64:cf:a0:93

4,  004003       1              2c:0e:3d:15:12:43

6,  NULL         0              2c:0e:3d:15:125

7,  004003       1              34:f3:9a:ee:53:a9

8,  004023       1              38:0B:40:DC:BA:3A

9,  NULL         0              4c:66:41:11:26:16

This is the table, and data is required for all customer, unknown customer and known customer.

output like: uniquely find the records by phonemacaddress.

count Customer,| customer type|
7                 all

3                 unknown customer

4                 known customer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, this is no CodeProviding platform, you should provide your best not working attemt in Code, so someone can correct it.

Comment: Id #5 is missing from the table.

Answer (score 4):

You could use union and count

```
 select count(*), 'all'
 from customer
 union 
 select count(*), 'unknown customer'
 from customer
 where isKnowCustomer = 0
 union 
 select count(*), 'known customer'
 from customer
 where isKnowCustomer = 1
```

Comment: This results in three scans of the table.  `GROUP BY IsKnownCustomer WITH ROLLUP` *(or equivalent)* requires only one scan.  Also, you should use `UNION ALL` in cases such as your example *(which can indeed be an Extremely powerful and useful pattern)*  to avoid the additional overhead of `UNION`s de-duplicating of the results.

Answer (score 1):

I would just put this in one row:

```
select count(*) as all,
       sum(IsKnownCustomer) as known,
       sum(1 - IsKnownCustomer) as unknown
from t;
```

I'm not sure why you would want three rows rather than three columns.

If you do, you can do:

```
select (case when isKnownCustomer = 0 then 'Unknown'
             when isKnownCustomer = 1 then 'Known'
             else 'All'
        end) as which, count(*)
from t
group by grouping sets ( (IsKnownCustomer), () )
```

Comment: Same result, but why not just use `GROUP BY IsKnownCustomer WITH ROLLUP`?

Comment: @MatBailie . . . `grouping sets` is a more general syntax, so it is easier for me to remember one way to do something -- but `with rollup` is also totally fine.

Answer (score 1):

Below SQL would help you.

```
SELECT  
    SUM(CASE WHEN Isknown = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Known Customer',
    SUM(CASE WHEN Isknown = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Unknown Customer',
    COUNT(*) AS 'All' 
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate the table with one scan, then use `UNPIVOT`.

```
SELECT [count customer], [customer type]
  FROM ( --aggregations will be placed side-by-side
         SELECT COUNT(*) [all]
               ,COUNT(CASE WHEN IsKnownCustomer = 0 THEN 1 END) [unknown customer]
               ,COUNT(CASE WHEN IsKnownCustomer = 1 THEN 1 END) [known customer]
          FROM CustomerTable
       ) AS dT
UNPIVOT( --unpivot, will separate aggregations by row
         [count customer] FOR [customer type] IN ([all], [unknown customer], [known customer])
       ) AS unp
```

Creates Output:

```
count customer  customer type
9               all
3               unknown customer
6               known customer
```

Here is the full code in SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/54e54/2/0